# Mockito scala Ambiguous reference to overloaded definition

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito, scalatest

I am trying to mock `resultset` in scala using mockito like below

`val resultset = mock[java.util.ResultSet]`

However when i try to mock `getString` method like below i am getting **ambiguous reference to overloaded definition error** as getString can accept either string or int

`(resultset.getString _).expects(any[String]).returns("test")`

what could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is an known issue with Java/Scala interop, please migrate to [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala) which solves it.

Then you can use the examples amer has posted (just use the methods from the traits and not from the `Mockito` class) or you can try the scala syntax

```
resultset.getString(*) returns "test"
```

Comment: Thx for the updated post. I though he is using it. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this maybe:

```
Mockito.when(resultset.getString(any())) thenReturn "test"
```

or

```
 Mockito.when(resultset.getString(anyString())) thenReturn "test"
```

Comment: How about mocking actual string ?
`Mockito.when(resultset.getString("someString")) thenReturn "test"`